# How to modify variables and constraints of an existing Google OR-Tools Constraint Programming model?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have written a constraint programming model using Google OR Tools in Python, which uses CP solver. I need to run that model multiple times, and in each run I modify constraints. Currently, I create the model object from scratch, every time I want to run the model. Is there anyway, I can modify variables/constraints of an existing model, so that I don't need to build the model from scratch everytime?

To give better context, please consider the below sample model.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()
num_vals = 3
a = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals -1, 'a')
b = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals -1, 'b')
c = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals -1, 'c')
model.Add(a == b)
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)
```

Now, in the 2nd run of the problem, I want to do following changes.

1. Change the upper bound of variable c to `5`
2. Delete the constraint `a==b`
3. Create a new constraint `a==c`

How can this be achieved without building the model from scratch?

Answer (score 7):

Here's the code following Laurent's answer:

```py
# 1. change c upper bound to 5
c.Proto().domain[:] = []
c.Proto().domain.extend(cp_model.Domain(0, 5).FlattenedIntervals())
```

```py
# 2. delete a == b
# assuming that you did a_eq_b = model.Add(a == b)
a_eq_b.Proto().Clear()
```

Comment: I will check. But I thought there is a getter on the underlying proto.

Comment: You are absolutely right, not sure how I forgot, edited

Comment: The method does not work

Comment: Edited with the new syntax, thanks @Optimizationteam

Comment: Is it possible to explain how to define a new domain from some values ? 
at the moment the domain of variable will be [0,1,2,3,4,5]

how can we set it to for exapmple [0 , 3, 5 ] ?

Comment: Try: `cp_model.Domain.FromValues([0, 3, 5]).FlattenedIntervals()`

Answer (score 3):

First, you can have a look at this [page](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/model.md).

The basic idea is that you can manipulate the underlying protobuf stored in the cp_model class. The only rule is that you should not delete a variable as they are referenced by index in other constraints.

To delete a constraint, just call Clear() on it (see this [link](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html)).
To add a constraint, use the normal API.
To change the domain of a variable, you can manipulate its domain. Be aware that the domain is stored as a flattened list of disjoint closed intervals.

Comment: The link is broken.